# Two complementary continued fractions that are algebraic numbers

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, gamma-function, continued-fractions, hyperbolic-functions

Define the two similar continued fractions,

$$x=\cfrac{1}{km\color{blue}+\cfrac{(m-1)(m+1)} {3km\color{blue}+\cfrac{(2m-1)(2m+1)}{5km\color{blue}+\cfrac{(3m-1)(3m+1)}{7km\color{blue}+\ddots}}}}\tag1$$

$$y=\cfrac{1}{km\color{blue}-\cfrac{(m-1)(m+1)} {3km\color{blue}-\cfrac{(2m-1)(2m+1)}{5km\color{blue}-\cfrac{(3m-1)(3m+1)}{7km\color{blue}-\ddots}}}}\tag2$$

For integer $m>1$, it seems $(1)$ and $(2)$ are *algebraic numbers*. For $(1)$ and the special case $k=1$, then,

$$x=\tan\Big(\frac{\pi}{4m}\Big)=\frac{1}{4m}\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{2m-1}{4m}\Big)\Gamma\Big(\frac{2m+1}{4m}\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{4m-1}{4m}\Big)\Gamma\Big(\frac{4m+1}{4m}\Big)}\tag3$$

and is adapted from Nicco's cfrac in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739431/conjectured-general-continued-fraction-for-the-quotient-of-gamma-functions). For $(2)$ and general $k\neq1$,

$$y =\tanh\Big(\frac{1}{2m}\,\log (R)\Big)= \frac{R^{1/m}-1}{R^{1/m}+1};\;\;R=\frac{k+1}{k-1}\tag4$$

and [solves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581041/how-to-solve-in-radicals-this-family-of-equations-for-any-degree-k),

$$\frac{ (1+y)^{m}-(1-y)^{m}}{(1+y)^{m}+(1-y)^{m}}=\frac{1}{k}\tag5$$

hence $x,y$ are *radicals*.

**Questions:**

1. What is the formula for $x$ for general $k>1$?
2. Does $y$ also have a formula in terms of *gamma functions*?

Comment: Inspired by achilles' proof in this [post](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783972/a-general-continued-fraction-satisfying-fraci-theta-sqrtzmi-theta-s?__=1515657880),one is led to conjecture 

$$F(k,z,m)=\cfrac{1}{km+\cfrac{z(m-1)(m+1)} {3km+\cfrac{z(2m-1)(2m+1)}{5km+\cfrac{z(3m-1)(3m+1)}{7km+\ddots}}}}$$
 
Then $$F(k,z,m) =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\tan(\frac{1}{m}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}}{k}\right))$$

Comment: @Nicco: That's a very nice generalization.