# a general continued fraction satisfying $\frac{(i+\Theta\sqrt{z})^m}{(i-\Theta\sqrt{z})^m}=\frac{(ik+\sqrt{z})^{m+1}}{(ik-\sqrt{z})^{m+1}}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, radicals, continued-fractions

Given any *natural number* $m\gt2$, let $z$,$k$ be *complex numbers*, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and consider the general continued fraction

$$\Theta(k,z,m)=\cfrac{(m+1)}{km+\cfrac{z(0m-1)(2m+1)} {3km+\cfrac{z(m-1)(3m+1)}{5km +\cfrac{z(2m-1)(4m+1)}{7km+\cfrac{z(3m-1)(5m+1)}{9km+\ddots}}}}}$$

The variable $\Theta$ has the property of satisfying the polynomial equation of $m$th degree

$$\frac{(i+\Theta\sqrt{z})^m}{(i-\Theta\sqrt{z})^m}=\frac{(ik+\sqrt{z})^{m+1}}{(ik-\sqrt{z})^{m+1}}\tag1$$

$k\neq\pm i$ , $k\neq 0$ ,$z\neq-k^2$,$z\neq 0$

Both continued fractions in this [post](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778673/a-pair-of-continued-fractions-that-are-algebraic-numbers-and-related-to-a2b2/1782441?__=2051448193#1782441) are just the special cases $z =\pm 1$.

It also obeys a very fundamental transformation property

$$\Theta(k,z,m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\Theta(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}},1,m)\tag2$$

***P.S.***:After applying property $(1)$ and $(2)$,we arrive at the elegant solution

$$\Theta(k,z,m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\dfrac{-\frac{ik}{\sqrt{z}}\left(\dfrac{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}+i}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}-i}\right)^{1/m}+\left(\dfrac{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}+i}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}-i}\right)^{1/m}+\frac{ik}{\sqrt{z}}+1}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}\left(\dfrac{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}+i}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}-i}\right)^{1/m}+i\left(\dfrac{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}+i}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}-i}\right)^{1/m}+\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}-i}$$

> Q: How do we prove rigorously that the continued fraction does satisfy the polynomial equation?

Comment: Roots of polynomials of degree $5$ or higher do not **necessarily** have roots expressable in terms of radicals.

Comment: @AdamHughes: I've fixed Nicco's equation $(1)$. This particular equation ***does*** have a solution in radicals for integer $m>1$. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581041/how-to-solve-in-radicals-this-family-of-equations-for-any-degree-k).

Comment: @Nicco: I've revised your formula $(1)$. This special form ***is solvable in radicals*** for all integer $m>1$. (I've cited a link in my comment to Adam.) If you observe the two special cases $z=\pm1$, notice that the $LHS$ is just an expression in the unknown variable multiplied by a constant.

Comment: @ Tito Piezas III : thanks, but the formula $$\frac{(i+\Theta\sqrt{z})^m}{(i-\Theta\sqrt{z})^m}=\frac{(ik+\sqrt{z})^{m+1}}{(ik-\sqrt{z})^{m+1}}$$ is solvable in radicals(I have tested it). I think it should be incorporated back into the question since it's simpler and also includes k whereas C in this other formula is not known

Comment: does $k$ need to be an integer ?

Comment: @Nicco: I stand corrected. Your $(1)$ is a simpler and better version of my $(3)$.  :)

Comment: @AdamHughes: yes they must have, but not necessarily **finite** number of such radicals.

Comment: @mathreadler in algebra finite iterations are requisite, if you allow limits then you're in the realm of completions which is more analysis. And when one says a polynomial is "solvable by radicals" they mean all its roots are in a finite radical extension, which means no infinite towers.

Comment: @Nicco: You have an [unregistered account](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/252633). Please [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) it with your official one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, we will start with the case $z = 1$.
We will assume $k > 0$ and let $\cot\theta = k$ and $\mu_{\pm} = k \pm \sqrt{k^2+1}$.

The CF at hand has the form $$
\def\CF{\mathop{\LARGE\mathrm K}}
\CF_{\ell=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_\ell\gamma_{\ell-1}}{\beta_\ell}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\gamma_0 = 1\quad\text { and }\quad
\begin{cases}
\alpha_\ell &= \ell m + 1\\
\beta_\ell  &= k m (2\ell - 1)\\
\gamma_\ell &= \ell m - (m+1)
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ for }\quad\ell > 0
$$
Consider the associated linear recurrence relation:

$$\alpha_\ell f_{\ell-1} - \beta_\ell f_\ell = \gamma_\ell f_{\ell + 1}\quad\text{ for }\ell > 0\tag{*1}$$
Let $(u_\ell)_{\ell=0}^\infty$ and $(v_\ell)_{\ell=0}^\infty$ be the two solutions satisfying $(u_0,u_1) = (1,0)$ and $(v_0,v_1) = (0,1)$.
In terms of $u$ and $v$, it is easy to verify the convergents of CF
satisfy
$$L_n \stackrel{def}{=} \CF_{\ell=1}^n \frac{\alpha_\ell\gamma_{\ell-1}}{\beta_{\ell}} = -\frac{u_{n+1}}{v_{n+1}}
\quad\implies\quad
L_\infty \stackrel{def}{=} \CF_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha_\ell\gamma_{\ell-1}}{\beta_{\ell}} = -\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u_n}{v_n}$$
Notice $\alpha_\ell,\gamma_\ell \ne 0$ for all $\ell$ and following limits exist
$$
\alpha \stackrel{def}{=} 
\lim\limits_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{\alpha_\ell}{\ell m} = 1, 
\quad
\beta \stackrel{def}{=} 
\lim\limits_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{\beta_\ell}{\ell m}
= 2k
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\gamma \stackrel{def}{=} 
\lim\limits_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{\gamma_\ell}{\ell m}
= 1
$$
Furthermore, the associated polynomial
$$\alpha - \beta\lambda - \gamma\lambda^2 = 0 \quad\iff\quad
\lambda^2 +2k\lambda - 1 = 0$$
have roots $\lambda_{\pm} = -k \pm \sqrt{k^2+1} = \frac{1}{\mu_{\pm}}$ whose modulus are distinct. 
By Poincare-Perron theorem${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$, $(*1)$ has a pair of fundamental solutions $(p^{+}_\ell)_{\ell=0}^\infty$ and $(p^{-}_\ell)_{\ell=0}^\infty$ satisfying
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{p^{\pm}_{\ell+1}}{p^{\pm}_{\ell}} = \lambda_{\pm}$.

Expanding $u$, $v$ in terms of $p^{\pm}$ and notice $|\lambda_{-}| > 1 > |\lambda_{+}|$, we have

$$\begin{cases}
u_\ell &= A p^{+}_\ell + B p^{-}_\ell\\
v_\ell &= C p^{+}_\ell + D p^{-}_\ell
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
L_\infty = -\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A p^{+}_\ell + B p^{-}_\ell}{C p^{+}_\ell + D p^{-}_\ell} = -\frac{B}{D}$$
Construct a solution $(w_\ell)_{\ell=0}^\infty$ of $(*1)$ by setting $w_\ell = u_\ell + L_\infty v_\ell$, we have

$$w_\ell = ( A p^{+}_\ell + B p^{-}_\ell ) - \frac{B}{D}( C p^{+}_\ell + D p^{-}_\ell ) = \frac{AD-BC}{D} p^{+}_\ell
\quad\implies\quad
\lim_{\ell\to\infty} \frac{w_{\ell+1}}{w_\ell} = \lambda_{+}
$$
The corresponding OGF $\displaystyle\;\quad w(t) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty w_\ell t^\ell\quad$ will be analytic for $t < |\mu_{+}|$.
Let $a = \frac{1}{m}$, one can rescale $(*1)$ to the form:
$$(\ell + a) w_{\ell-1} - k(2\ell-1) w_{\ell} + (a + 1 - \ell) w_{\ell+1} = 0\quad\text{ for }\quad \ell > 0\tag{*2}$$

Let us first treat $a$ as a complex parameter with $-\frac32 < \Re a < -1$.

Multiply the $\ell^{th}$ entry of $(*2)$ by $t^\ell$ and start to sum from $\ell = 1$. If we let $g(t) = w(t) - 1$, we find

$$\begin{align}
& \left[t\frac{d}{dt} + a\right]\big\{t(1+g(t))\big\}
-k\left[2t\frac{d}{dt} - 1\right]g(t) 
+ \left[a+1 - t\frac{d}{dt}\right]\left\{\frac{g(t)}{t} - L_{\infty}\right\}
= 0\\
\iff &
(t^2 - 2kt - 1)g'(t)
+ \left((a+1)t + k + \frac{a+2}{t}\right) g(t)
+ (a+1)(t - L_\infty) = 0\\
\iff & g'(t) + \left[ -\frac{a+2}{t} + \frac{a+\frac32}{t - \mu_{+}} + \frac{a + \frac32}{t - \mu_{-}}\right] g(t) = (a+1)\frac{t - L_\infty}{1+2kt - t^2}\\
\iff &
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{(1+2kt-t^2)^{a+\frac32}}{t^{a+2}} g(t)\right]
= (a+1)\frac{(1+2kt-t^2)^{a+\frac12}}{t^{a+2}}(t-L_\infty)\\
\implies &
w(t) = 1 + (a+1)\frac{t^{a+2}}{(1+2kt-t^2)^{a+\frac32}}\left[\int_0^t 
\frac{(1+2ks-s^2)^{a+\frac12}}{s^{a+2}}(s-L_\infty) ds\right]
\end{align}
$$
For the range of choice of $a$, the coefficient in front of the square bracket is singular at $t = \mu_{-}$. Since $|\mu_{-}| < |\mu_{+1}|$, $w(t)$ is regular there. This means the integral in the square bracket need to vanish at $t = \mu_{-}$. From this, we can deduce

$$L_{\infty} = \frac{\Lambda(a,-a)}{\Lambda(a,-a-1)}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\Lambda(a,b) \stackrel{def}{=}
\int_0^{\mu_{-}}
s^{b-1}(1+2ks-s^2)^{a+\frac12} ds
$$
Let $c = a + b + \frac32$ and $\eta = \frac{\mu_{-}}{\mu_{+}}$, the integral $\Lambda(a,b)$ can be evaluated as

$$\begin{align}\Lambda(a,b) 
& = 
\int_0^{\mu_{-}}
s^{b-1}\left(1 - \frac{s}{\mu_{+}}\right)^{a+\frac12}\left(1 - \frac{s}{\mu_{-}}\right)^{a+\frac12} ds\\
&= \mu_{-}^b \int_0^1 s^{b-1}(1-s)^{c-b-1}\left(1-\eta s\right)^{a+\frac12} ds\\
&=^{\color{blue}{[2]}} \mu_{-}^b \frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}{\Gamma(c)}{}_2F_1\left(-a-\frac12,b;c; \eta\right)\\
&=^{\color{blue}{[3]}} \mu_{-}^b(1 - \eta)^{-b} \frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}{\Gamma(c)}
{}_2F_1\left(c+a+\frac12,b;c; \frac{\eta}{\eta - 1}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
Substitute this back into expression of $L_\infty$ and simplify, we get

$$L_\infty = -\frac{2(a+1)\mu_{-}}{1 - \eta}
\frac{
{}_2F_1\left(a+2,-a;\frac32; \frac{\eta}{\eta-1}\right)
}{
{}_2F_1\left(a+1,-(a+1);\frac12; \frac{\eta}{\eta-1}\right)
}
$$
Notice
$$
\frac{\mu_{-}}{1-\eta} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k^2+1}} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{2}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{\eta}{\eta - 1} = \frac{\sqrt{k^2+1}-k}{2\sqrt{k^2+1}} = \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}
$$
We get 
$$L_\infty = 
\frac{(a+1)\sin\theta
{}_2F_1\left(a+2,-a;\frac32; \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}\right)
}{
{}_2F_1\left(a+1,-a-1,\frac12; \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}\right)
}
$$
Compare this with following representation of 
[generalized Chebyshev's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Generalized_Chebyshev_polynomials) in terms of [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

$$\begin{cases}
T_a(\cos x) &= {}_2F_1\left(a,-a; \frac12; \frac12(1-\cos x)\right) = \cos(a x)\\
U_a(\cos x) &= (a+1){}_2F_1\left(a+2,-a; \frac32; \frac12(1 - \cos x)\right) = \frac{\sin((a+1)x)}{\sin x}
\end{cases}
$$
We find 
$$L_\infty = \tan((a+1)\theta) = \tan\left((a+1)\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

Up to what I see, there is nothing to stop us from analytic continuing this result
back to $a \in (0,1)$. This implies
$$\Theta(k,1,m) = \tan\left(\frac{m+1}{m}\tan^{-1}\frac1k\right)$$

Back to the case $z \ne 1$. The CF can be obtained by scaling $\alpha_\ell, \gamma_\ell$ by $\sqrt{z}$ for all $\ell > 0$ and $\gamma_0$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$. Since $(*1)$ is invariant when one rescale $\alpha_\ell, \beta_\ell, \gamma_\ell$ by same factor, scaling $\alpha_\ell, \gamma_\ell$ by $\sqrt{z}$ is equivalent to replace the $k$ in $\beta_\ell$ by $\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}$. 
As long as $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0 ]$, we have $\Re \sqrt{z} > 0$. One can verify the corresponding $\lambda_{\pm}$ have distinct modulus and above arguments remain valid.

As a result, the CF at hand has following closed form expression:

> For $k > 0$, $m > 1$ and $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$, $$\Theta(k,z,m) = 
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\Theta\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}},1,m\right) =
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\tan\left[\frac{m+1}{m}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}}{k}\right)\right]$$

The rest is obvious.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - 
  For more details of Poincare-Perron theorem and a proof of it, please consult Chapter 8 of Saber Elaydi's book [An Introduction to Difference Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441920013).
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - For $|t| < 1$ and $\Re c > \Re b > 0$, we have following
  [integral formula by Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type)
  $$\int_0^1 x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-tx)^{-a} dx = \frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}{\Gamma(c)} {}_2F_1(a,b;c;t)$$
- $\color{blue}{[3]}$ - We are using following Pfaff transformation here.

$${}_2F_1(a,b;c;t) = (1-t)^{-b} {}_2F_1\left(c-a,b;c;\frac{t}{t-1}\right)$$

Comment: Nice proof. I see you started by proving the case $z=1$ and then used the functional equation 
$$\Theta(k,z,m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\Theta(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}},1,m)$$ for the general case

Comment: @Nicco, yup. In any event, you can also deduce the functional equation through suitable rescaling of $t$ and $k$ in above derivation.

Comment: @ ahille hui :Indeed that's possible. Good Job achille

Comment: @ achille hui : perhaps you may be interested in this [problem](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739431/conjectured-general-continued-fraction-for-the-quotient-of-gamma-functions)

Comment: Assume analytic continuation continue to work, the RHS on the other problem is  simply $\frac{4(a+b)}{b-a}\Theta\left(1,1,-\frac{a+b}{2a}\right) = \frac{4(a+b)}{b-a}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{b-a}{b+a}\right)$. The $-\frac{a+b}{2a}$ there is taking the role of $m$ here.

Answer (score 2):

The case with $z \neq 1$ can be obtained from the case $z=1$, because you can just factor them out of the infinite fraction while changing $k$ accordingly.

Consider $k,m$ fixed, and let $(f_n)$ be the sequence of homographies $f_n(x) = a_n + b_n / x$, with $a_n = (2n-1)km$ and $b_n = ((n-1)m-1)((n+1)m+1)$ so that
$\Theta = \lim_{n \to \infty} (m+1)/ f_0 \circ f_1 \circ f_2 \circ f_3 \dots f_n(0)$" (well I guess this is where you put the $0$ but it shouldn't really matter)

(I think you should be able to define this more purely, if you call $x_n$ the attractive fixpoint of $f_0 \circ \dots \circ f_n$, then $\Theta = \lim (m+1)/x_n$, but leaving a zero is fine).

Now consider a nonzero complex number $z$ and let $g(x) = x/z$. After conjugation by $g$, you get $g^{-1} \circ f_n \circ g (x) = za_n + (z^2b_n)/x$, and so $\lim_{n \to \infty} g^{-1} \circ f_0 \circ f_1 \circ \dots f_n (0)$ is given by the infinite fraction where we replace $a_n$ and $b_n$ with $za_n$ and $z^2 b_n$. This amounts to replacing $k$ with $zk$ and adding a $z^2$ factor in front of every numerator.

Thus, $g^{-1}((m+1)/\Theta(k,1)) = (m+1)/\Theta(kz,z^2)$, so $z\Theta(kz,z^2) = \Theta(k,1)$

If we know the conjecture for $\Theta(k,1)$, we have $\frac{(i+\Theta(k,1))^m}{(i-\Theta(k,1))^m}=\frac{(ik+1)^{m+1}}{(ik-1)^{m+1}}$

And $\frac{(i+z\Theta(kz,z^2))^m}{(i-z\Theta(kz,z^2))^m}=\frac{(ik+1)^{m+1}}{(ik-1)^{m+1}} = \frac{(ikz+z)^{m+1}}{(ikz-z)^{m+1}}$. So letting $w =z^2$ and $k' = kz$ we obtain $\frac{(i+\sqrt w \Theta(k',w))^m}{(i-\sqrt w\Theta(k',w))^m} = \frac{(ik'+\sqrt w)^{m+1}}{(ik'- \sqrt w)^{m+1}}$ (the choice of square root doesn't matter as long as we pick the same on both side)

Comment: yes i only show that the case $z \neq 1$ reduces to the case $z=1$ after rescaling things by $z^2$. so it would make this a duplicate of an earlier question

Comment: @ mercio :that's because of the tranformation property $z\Theta(kz,z^2)=\Theta(k,1)$ which is very fundamental.