# Reference in the literature for the first use of the K notation (continued fractions)

Tags: reference-request, notation, continued-fractions

In my posts, I always use the following notation for the continued fractions:

$$
a_0 + \operatorname*{K}_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = a_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{a_1 + \cfrac{b_2}{a_2 + \cfrac{b_3}{a_3 + \dotsb}}}
$$

(see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097510/found-an-recursive-identity-involving-a-continued-fraction-for-which-some-simp), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230651/a-conjectured-continued-fraction-for-phi-phi) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515035/curious-about-an-empirically-found-continued-fraction-for-tanh)).

I find it convenient and it can be found for instance in [Continued Fractions with Applications](http://store.elsevier.com/Continued-Fractions-with-Applications/L_-Lorentzen/isbn-9780444892652/) by  Lorentzen & Waadeland.

The first place where I saw it was on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction) where it is said:

> Carl Friedrich Gauss evoked the more familiar infinite product Π when he devised this notation:
>   $$
> {\displaystyle x=b_{0}+{\underset {i=1}{\overset {\infty }{\mathrm {K} }}}{\frac {a_{i}}{b_{i}}}.\,}
> $$
>   Here the "K" stands for Kettenbruch, the German word for "continued fraction". This is probably the most compact and convenient way to express continued fractions; however, it is not widely used by English typesetters.

I browsed (very quickly) all articles from Gauss where the topic of continued fractions was obvious without seeing it once; for this reason I am not sure the statement on this page is true.

Would someone have a more precise reference?

Comment: I had the same question as you asked here.  Did you ever find an answer, or did you ever find a paper by Gauss using the $K$-notation?