# A conjectured continued fraction related to a 2F1 hypergeometric function (and a formula for π)

Tags: pi, continued-fractions, hypergeometric-function, conjectures

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097510/found-an-recursive-identity-involving-a-continued-fraction-for-which-some-simp), some months ago, I described a continued fraction for which I was trying to find an identity. I finally found what I was looking for, and I will publish an answer to this question in the days or weeks to come by focusing to what was asked at that time. But now, I am opening a separate question for a new interest: *Could the conjectured statements below be proved? Do these identities sound familiar to anyone? etc.*

My identity finally is:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathcal{K}\left(a,x\right)&=&\displaystyle\operatorname*{K}_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{
\left(n+1\right)\left(\left(a-1\right)x-n\right)a}{\left(n+1\right)\left(a+1\right)}\\[12pt]
&=&
\displaystyle\frac{\left(a-1\right)x-1}{x+1}\;
\displaystyle{}_{2}F_{1}\left(1,ax\;; 2+x\;; a^{-1}\right)
\end{array}
\tag{1} \label{1}
$$

### Two functional identities

I empirically noticed two functional identities, namely:

$$
2+\mathcal{K}\left(a,x\right)+\mathcal{K}\left(1-a,x\right) \;=\; 0
\tag{2} \label{2}
$$
and (with $\textrm{B}$ the Beta function):
$$
\begin{array}{l}
2+\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}\mathcal{K}\left(a,x\right)
+\displaystyle\frac{a-1}{a}\mathcal{K}\left(a/\left(a-1\right), \left(a-1\right)x\right)\\[8pt]
\qquad\qquad\;=\;
ax\left(a-1\right)^{x-1}\left(\displaystyle\frac{a}{a-1}\right)^{ax-2}\textrm{B}\left(x,\left(a-1\right)x\right)
\end{array}
\tag{3} \label{3}
$$
I already told about the latter in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230651/a-conjectured-continued-fraction-for-phi-phi).

### A finite summation

While studying the polynomials from the [initial question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097510/found-an-recursive-identity-involving-a-continued-fraction-for-which-some-simp), I finally found the following summation:
$$
\mathcal{K}\left(a,x\right)\;=\;
\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle 2\sum_{k=2}^{\left(a-1\right)x-1}
  \left(k-1\right){{ak/\left(a-1\right)}\choose{k}}
                  {a\left(\left(a-1\right)x-k\right)/\left(a-1\right)
                      \choose{\left(a-1\right)x-k}}
                      }
             {\displaystyle\left(\left(a-1\right)x-2\right){{ax}\choose{x}}}
\tag{4} \label{4}
$$
(when  $(a-1)x$ is an integer greater than 2).

### A formula for $\pi$

I tried several computer algebra systems and found the `hyperexpand` function in Sympy to be able of simplifying the ${}_2F_1$ hypergeometric function for many rational cases. My favorite case comes from $\mathcal{K}\left(-3, 1/2\right)$, after some cosmetic changes:
$$
\pi
\;=\;
\operatorname*{K}_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{
81\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)/16}{3\sqrt{3}\left(n+1\right)/2} 
\tag{5} \label{5}
$$
The formula for $\phi^\phi$ in the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230651/a-conjectured-continued-fraction-for-phi-phi) was also a specific case for the same continued fraction.

Comment: Isn't the continued fraction representation for $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ functions pretty well-known? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction#The_series_2F1

Comment: It looks to me that your $(1)$ follows from Gauss' continued fraction through simple rearrangements.